# Modify c# Windows Forms control library

Tags: c#, windows, forms, controls

I have a c# Windows Forms control library, but there is no sln file with it.
I would like to modify this project, so I think I need an sln file to open it and create an other dll.

I tried a solution, but it did not work.
I create a new c# Windows Forms control library, I named it as the original library name. 
I renamed the UserControl1.cs as the original mainfile name.
I bult it, it has worked, yet.

After that I copied all of the .cs files from the original library to the new library.
Of course overwrite the new files with the original files.
I tried to build it again, but I got an error message: "dll does not contain any usercontrol types"

The original folder contains a __csproj.user file, but my new project does not contain it.

What did I wrong? How can I modify the original c# Windows Forms control library oe how can I create an sln file for it?

Comment: Do you have the .csproj file from the old project? If youe just add the old project to your empty solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `.sln` file, that's fine visual studio will create it for you when you open a `.csproj` file and try to save the project.

All you have to do is open the `.csproj` file in visual studio and save it.

Comment: I got the .sln file, but the error message remained unfortunately.
(Otherwise, if I add the original project to an other solution to use the form control it works correctly)

Comment: @SzilviaLázár You said you don't have the .sln file for the old project? Do you have `.csproj` file for old project? I'm not talking about new project you created.

Comment: In the old project I did not have .sln, but I have .csproj. As you write, I saved the project, and after that I got the .sln file.
But the error message remained. I don't know why do I get this error message.

Comment: What is the error message? `dll does not contain any usercontrol types`?

Comment: That means your project doesn't have any `UserControl`. If your project type is user control library you need atleast one user control. Otherwise you need to use `class libray` project rather than control library

Comment: If I don't create a new project, I only open the original project by the csporj file or the sln file, I get this errormessage, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58410/discussion-between-szilvia-lazar-and-sriram-sakthivel).